# How to load ASP.Net Grid from a multi table Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, dataset

I am new to ASP.Net and I want to read following XML in to ASP.Net Grid.
When I load the xml into DataSet and use the following code, it only shows me first table from the XML.

```
DataSet DS = new DataSet();        
DS.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(".\\data\\demo_portfolio.xml"));        
GridView1.DataSource = DS;    
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**XML TO READ**

```
<portfolio>
  <script>
    <name>"HDFC.BSE"</name>
    <row>
      <PurchasePrice>2433.75</PurchasePrice>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-01-01</PurchaseDate>
      <PurchaseQty>5</PurchaseQty>
      <CommissionPaid>20</CommissionPaid>
      <CostofInvestment>12188.75</CostofInvestment>
    </row>
    <row>
      <PurchasePrice>2455.30</PurchasePrice>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-01-20</PurchaseDate>
      <PurchaseQty>4</PurchaseQty>
      <CommissionPaid>30</CommissionPaid>
      <CostofInvestment>9851.20</CostofInvestment>
    </row>
    <row>
      <PurchasePrice>1874.90</PurchasePrice>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-03-12</PurchaseDate>
      <PurchaseQty>6</PurchaseQty>
      <CommissionPaid>30</CommissionPaid>
      <CostofInvestment>11279.40</CostofInvestment>
    </row>
  </script>
</portfolio>
```

Comment: My expected output is as follows in Grid (with Name repeating on each row): Name|PurchasePrice|PurchaseDate|PurchaseQty|CommisionPaid|CostofInvestment

Comment: A Gridview is a 2 dimensional object that will only display one table.  You would need a separate GridView for each table or need to join multiple tables by a common key.

Comment: The DataSet ReadXml is limited to only 4 levels of descendants.  After 4 levels the DS get fragmented into tables that really cannot be used or combined.  Once you get beyond the 4 levels you should sue other Xml parsing methods to put data into 2 dimensional objects before putting into a GridView.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question... How can I show above XML in single grid? If yes, appreciate if someone can help me with code snippet. Also can ASP.Net GridView allows selection of row? I don't have to use DataSet, and is there any other alternative?

Comment: Just bind to table "row" :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["row"];

Comment: @jdweng, that only shows the "row" table in the Grid. What I want is to show in the grid row as below:
"HDFC.BSE"  | PurchasePrice |  PurchaseDate  |  PurchaseQty  |  CommissionPaid  | CostofInvestment

"HDFC.BSE"  | 2433.75  | 2020-01-01 | 5 | 20 | 12188.75

Comment: Can i execute a join query on two table in DataSet? Will that give me a resultant new table?  I do not have any connection as I am not working with any database, so the join has to be within DataSet only.

Comment: Any help on the above question is sincerly appreciated. I am stuck.....

Comment: Is the xml you posted the entire xml or only a portion?  I would need to see more to verify fix.  Right now the name is in a separate table "name" which has one row and one column.  There is nothing that can be used to join. when looking at one script tag.

Comment: There can be multiple blocks of 
<script>
   <name>one more stock symbol</name>
   <row>
     <PurchasePrice>2433.75</PurchasePrice>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-01-01</PurchaseDate>
      <PurchaseQty>5</PurchaseQty>
      <CommissionPaid>20</CommissionPaid>
      <CostofInvestment>12188.75</CostofInvestment>
    </row>
    <row>
      <PurchasePrice>2455.30</PurchasePrice>
      <PurchaseDate>2020-01-20</PurchaseDate>
      <PurchaseQty>4</PurchaseQty>
      <CommissionPaid>30</CommissionPaid>
      <CostofInvestment>9851.20</CostofInvestment>
    </row>
</script>

Comment: When I load this XML into DataSet, it creates two tables. Each has a "script_id" column, which is added by Load method. And the "script_id" in each table can be mapped.
For example, the first table (name = "script") has row with two columns "name" = "HDFC.BSE" and "script_id" = 0 and its associated "row" table has a column "script_id" = 0 along with other columns for each node.Subsequently for each "script" table the "script_id" is incremented by 1 as if it is an Auto Increment column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom xml linq parser to fill the datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PurchasePrice", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("PurchaseDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("PurchaseQty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CommissionPaid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CostofInvestment", typeof(decimal));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement script in doc.Descendants("script"))
            {
                string name = (string)script.Element("name");
                foreach (XElement row in script.Elements("row"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        name,
                        (decimal)row.Element("PurchasePrice"),
                        (DateTime)row.Element("PurchaseDate"),
                        (int)row.Element("PurchaseQty"),
                        (int)row.Element("CommissionPaid"),
                        (decimal)row.Element("CostofInvestment")
                    });
                }
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU @jdweng, this is perfect solution.